# Memory allocation in php

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, internal-server-error

I'm developing a facebook application.
It's still in a test phase so only me and a friend are testing the app.
Our app is hosted on a shared server, with 4GB of virtual memory.
Since a couple of days, we are getting 500 internal errors. The log shows:

> (12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for ..., referer: http://...

The moment these errors occur, I see peeks in the virtual memory usage up to 4GB.
I'm not trained in memory management, but our code isn't that complex or heavy either. Is it possible that only 2 testers boost the memory to 4GB by just accessing the app?

The funny thing is, the error/peek **only occurs once in a while**. We do the exact same thing for hours and hours, without any noticable virtual memory usage (way below 1GB).

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's hard to catch a problem without seeing any code…

Comment: I'd be happy to share some code, however, our app contains +50 php files. Since I'm no memory expert, I'm not sure which part to share...

Comment: Check for places when you can safely use unset, maybe you are generating some PDFs? (it's highly memory-hungry)

Comment: There are places where we are generating PDF's, and we're planning on replacing this with an alternative since it takes up a bunch of CPU too. However, the memory usage peeks don't occur on PDF generation. Can a PDF generated 5hours ago affect the memory 5hours later?

Comment: lots of loops, opening large files, creating large files, long running processes storing lots of data... these are all things that can effect the memory usage. Have you tried to see exactly what processes are running when the memory usage jumps up? also some code example would be better help

Answer (score 0):

use

> ini_set('memory_limit','2024MB') in php file